# Как реализовать на Java операцию & из C++?

Tags: java

Пытаюсь реализовать шифр "Кузнечика" на Java. Но встала проблема. На С++ есть функция, которую я просто не знаю как реализовать на Java. Ниже представлена моя реализация, но компилятору не нравятся операции с &.

```
char mul_gf256(char x, char y)
{
    char z = 0x0;
    while (y)
    {
        if (y & 0x01)
            z ^= x;
        x = (x << 0x01) ^ (x & 0x80 ? 0xC3 : 0x00);
        y >>= 1;
    }
    return z;
}
```

Реализацию на с++ можно глянуть на гитхабе https://github.com/mjosaarinen/kuznechik/blob/master/kuznechik_128bit.c

Answer (score 2):

Компилятору не нравятся побитовые операции с типом `сhar` (точнее - в конце, т.к. `char` не подходит для данной задачи)

Эквивалентом сишного `char`  - однобайтового с диапазоном `-128..127` в Java будет `byte`

(в то время как в Java `сhar` двухбайтовый `0..65535` )

Вот доведённый до компилируемого состояния код (корректность не проверял).

```
byte mul_gf256(byte x, byte y)
{
    byte z = 0x0, first, second;
    while (y!=0)
    {
        if ((y & 0x01) !=0)
            z ^= x;
        first = (byte) (x << 1);
        if (x < 0)
            second = -61;
        else    
            second = 0;
        x = (byte) ((first) ^ (second));
        y >>= 1;
    }
    return z;
}
```

---

Хотя с `char` и можно выполнять арифметические действия, в большинстве случаев при этом тип повышается до int, так что при присвоении результата `char` потребуется приведение типа.

```
char a, b, c;
    a =  'A';
    a++;
    b = (char)(a+1);
    c = (char) (a & b);
```

Comment: В С++ изначально тоже byte. В char это уже я перевел по чей-то рекомендации. Однако, если использовать byte, то ошибка остается той же. В том-то и проблема.

Comment: @coolbober, в C++ нет типа `byte`. Вообще отсутствует. Если вам встретился тип `byte`, значит где-то выше есть что-то вроде `typedef unsigned char byte`.

Comment: `byte` в java тоже расширяется до `int`, и поскольку он знаковый, `y >>= 1;` может не обнулить `y` никогда. В [реализации](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/5d17720a0d5d61f2b6b198a059caccbda811724f/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/GOST3412_2015Engine.java#L75) Bouncy Castle для борьбы с этим в цикле есть счетчик. Кмк проще сделать локальные переменные `int`, привести аргументы метода к `int` через `a & 0xFF` и в конце привести результат. Не знаю, как это будет по скорости.

Comment: @zRrr Угу, на правый сдвиг я и не обратил внимания. `y = (byte) ((y & 0xFF)>>1);` решит проблему?

Comment: @Mbo да. изначальный подход с char тоже работает

Comment: @zRrr Меня смутило, что в java нет uint8 типа.

Comment: @freim , ну да, так оно и есть

Comment: @zRrr глянул реализацию, очень похоже на правду, но реализовать простейшую проверку ГОСТовскую не выходит. Точнее я-то ее делаю, только вот результат выходит не тот, который должен быть